# Manipulate unittest's Fixture classmethods Via A Metaclass

Tags: python, python-unittest, metaclass, class-method

I'd like to have a metaclass for subclasses of [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase), which will cause *all* methods to log when they're starting and finishing, including e.g., [the `@classmethod`s `setUp` and `tearDown` and their variants](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures).

Unfortunately, the `unittest` framework is very particular about the names of methods, and modifying them causes the framework not to find them. Using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176396/nose-unittest-testcase-and-metaclass-auto-generated-test-methods-not-discove), I have something like the following:

```
  class _UTMeta(type):                  
      def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict_): 
          new_dict = {}              
          for fn_name, fn in dict_.items():                          
              if fn_name.startswith('test_'):                  
                  new_dict[fn_name] = lambda self: _UTMeta._wrapped_test_function(self, fn_name, fn)
                  new_dict[fn_name].__name__ = fn_name # (**)
              else:                        
                  new_dict[fn_name] = fn
          return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, new_dict)

      @staticmethod
      def _wrapped_test_function(self, name, fn):
          print 'starting', name
          _test_logger.info('starting ' + name)
          print 'finished', name
```

Note the line with the comment `# (**)` - without it, `unittest` doesn't recognize the methods as test methods.

This works for the regular `test_*` methods, but not for the `classmethod`s. To illustrate the problem, I'll use the `classmethod setUpClass`. If I try to do exactly the same as the above, i.e., add

```
          if fn_name == 'setUpClass':                                      
              new_dict[fn_name] = lambda self: _UTMeta._wrapped_test_function(self, fn_name, fn)                            
              new_dict[fn_name].__name__ = fn_name
```

then I get:

```
ERROR: setUpClass (__main__._VersionDataTest)

TypeError: unbound method setUpClass() must be called with _VersionDataTest instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

However, if I try to [properly add a dynamic classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929543/how-can-i-dynamically-create-class-methods-for-a-class-in-python)

```
          if fn_name == 'setUpClass':                                      
              new_dict[fn_name] = classmethod(lambda self: _UTMeta._wrapped_test_function(self, fn_name, fn))                            
              new_dict[fn_name].__name__ = fn_name
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Finally, if I omit the `.__name__` manipulation, `unittest` doesn't call this fixture method at all.

(**Note** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610482/add-log-separators-to-all-fixtures-in-unittests/32616275#32616275) asks something similar, but the accepted answer assumed that these methods are not classmethods, and so is completely wrong IMHO.)